# Java - making a static reference to the non-static field list

Tags: java, class, static, instantiation, private-members

I've just been experimenting and found that when I run the rolling code, it does not compile and I can't figure out why.

My IDE says 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field list', but I don't really understand what or why this is. Also what else does it apply to, i.e.: is it just private variables and or methods too and why?:

```
public class MyList {

    private List list;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

However, when I change it to the following, it DOES work:

```
public class MyList {

    private List list;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MyList().exct();
    }

    public void exct() {
        list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: The main method is static. It only has access to static member variables and functions of the enclosing class. The error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you're trying to create a singleton factory.  If that's your goal, you should change `private List list;
` to `private static List list;`

Comment: @Perception: So if he changes the `private List list;` to `private static List list;` in the first code, it should work???

Comment: @noMAD - Yes, though for this simple example he really should just declare the list in his main method anyway.

Comment: @Perception: Thanks, just have one last doubt, this applies too all static methods right? Not just `main()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static fields are fields that are shared across all instances of the class.
non-static/member fields are specific to an instance of the class.

Example:

```
public class Car {
  static final int tireMax = 4;
  int tires;
}
```

Here it makes sense that any given car can have any number of tires, but the maximum number is the same across all cars.
If we made the `tireMax` variable changeable, modifying the value would mean that all cars can now have more (or less) tires.

The reason your second example works is that you're retrieving the `list` of a new MyList instance. In the first case, you are in the static context and not in the context of a specific instance, so the variable `list` is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are calling non-static field from static content, which is not possible.
In the second one you are calling ext function on MyList object, which has access to that field.