# non static method ... cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

Here is the error message

`non static method hero(double,double,double) cannot be reference from a static context`

Here is the class method.

```
class MyMath {
  double hero(double n1, double n2, double n3)
  {
    double n4;
    double n5;
    n4 = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 2;
    n5 = Math.sqrt((n4 * (n4 - n1) * (n4 - n2) * (n4 - n3)));
    return n5;
  }
}
```

Here is the main program

```
double length_of_a;
double length_of_b;
double length_of_c;
double area_of_triangle;

area_of_triangle = (double) MyMath.hero(length_of_a,length_of_b,length_of_c);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - making a static reference to the non-static field list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200740/java-making-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field-list)

Answer (score 1):

Your hero method should put as

```
static double hero(double n1, double n2, double n3){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your method `hero` to be called using class name, make it `static`. Otherwise simply create a `MyMath` object and call the function.

```
MyMath m = new MyMath();
area_of_triangle = m.hero(length_of_a,length_of_b,length_of_c); //No need to typecast too
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `hero` is not static. That means that you can only call it on an instance of class `MyMath`. You are trying to call it as if it is a static method here:

```
area_of_triangle = (double) MyMath.hero(length_of_a,length_of_b,length_of_c);
```

Either make the `hero` method `static`, or create an instance of `MyMath` and call the method on it.

```
// Solution 1: Make hero static
class MyMath {
    static double hero(double n1, double n2, double n3)
        // ...

// Solution 2: Call hero on an instance of MyMath
MyMath m = new MyMath();

area_of_triangle = m.hero(length_of_a,length_of_b,length_of_c);
```

Note: Casting the result of the method to `double` is not necessary, the method already returns a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hero()` method is not set to static. You can either make `hero()` a static method like so:

```
static double hero(double n1, double n2, double n3)
{
    ...
```

or you can create a new instance of MyMath like:

```
MyMath newMath = new MyMath();
```

and then call:

```
newMyMath.hero(length_of_a,length_of_b,length_of_c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you try to access `MyMath.hero` as if it were a `static` method. In order to fix this, you must either declare the method `hero` as `static` or first create an object of type `MyMath` and call the method from that object.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is static and java does not allow to have a reference of a non-static obj in a static method.
So You should either make the hero() method also static or reference it from a non-static method.