# Getting error while using .nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting this error: **"cannot make a static reference to the nonstatic field"** everytime I try to execute a line of code with `.nextInt()` in it.

Here are the lines of code that could affect (that I can think of):

```
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Could you add more of your code ?

Comment: Post more code. There are no problems with what you wrote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - making a static reference to the non-static field list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200740/java-making-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you're trying to access `input` in a static method, which I'm assuming it to be the `main()` method. Something like this

```
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int priceLocation = input.nextInt(); // This is not allowed as input is not static
```

You need to either make your `input` as `static` or may be move it inside the `static`(*main*) method.

**Solution1:** Make the `input` as `static`.

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
```

**Solution2:** Move the `input` inside the main(note that you can't use `input` in any other methods, if its moved inside the `main()`, as it'll be local to it).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: I am accessing this in the main method, so I guess it would be static, but how do I get around this?

Comment: Haha just did. You answered it too quickly, I had to wait 10 minutes until I could.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // make this static
```

If you accessing this inside static method. you have to make `input` static.

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
   // without static you will get that error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way you are defining input

```
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // notice private
int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
```

Private variables are defined in the class, outside methods like

```
class myclass{

    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    void methodname(){
        int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
    } 
}
```

Or if you want to define input inside the method

```
class myclass{
    void methodname(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // you can make this a final variable if you want
        int priceLocation = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```