# Beginner Java print a string

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    String name = "asad";

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("hello world" + name);//Display the string

        }
}
```

Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field name
. 
This is a code i tried, copy pasted yet it isn't working

Comment: You would have to make `name` a static variable: `static String name = "asad";`.

Comment: This is a very trivial error. The short answer is to make `name` static. I suggest reading up on static variables.

Comment: You need to understand static vs non-static first - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: if you just want it to not give you an error, you can declare `name` like:  `static String name;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Make Static Reference to Non-Static Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method)

Comment: asad is a very bad man

Comment: @wrongAnswer - I strongly recommend changing your *username* :P. People would think twice before up-voting your comment / answer :P

Comment: @TheLostMind I can't change it until 22 october till then I have to live with it :p...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error while using .nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947636/getting-error-while-using-nextint) (a question with "cannot make static reference to nonstatic field")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HelloWorld` is an class.  You can make multiple instances of this class.

Here's a sample making 2 instances of the class

```
HelloWorld helloWorld1 = new HelloWorld();
HelloWorld helloWorld2 = new HelloWorld();
```

right now, `name` is declared as an instance field.  That means that each instance of `HelloWorld` will have 1.

---

now, the `main` method is a static method.  That means that there is only 1 main method period.  you do not get a different main method for each instance of `HelloWorld`.  (main also happens to be a special static method that serves as the entry point of your program)

When you try to call `name` from `main`, your program doesn't have any instance of `name` to refer to.  If you had declared multiple `HelloWorld` objects, it wouldn't know which one's `name` to use.

---

If you just want to call `name` from `main`, you can make `name` a static field.  Remember, `static` means that you only have 1 `name` per program.

```
static String name = "asad";
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options.

1. Create an instance of HelloWorld and use new `HelloWorld().name`
2. Make `name` *static* and use `HelloWorld.name`

Answer (score 1):

Make the string you're referring to `static`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static String name = "asad";

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("hello world" + name);//Display the string

    }
}
```

[More on the difference between static and non-static fields/methods...](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/11/difference-between-static-vs-non-static-method-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can either make name static, or put it inside the main method:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String []args){
    String name = "asad";
    System.out.println("hello world" + name);//Display the string

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Why can't System.out.println() print a non-static variable

Comment: think of it like this: static means it will never change, so a nonchanging method printing something that changes confuses java.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static String name = "asad";

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("hello world" + name);//Display the string

    }
}
```

You can call only static attributes in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Create an instance of HelloWorld and get the field from the instance, `new HelloWorld().name`
2. Change `name` to a `static` or class field
3. Move the declaration of `name` into `main()`

So,

```
String name = "asad";
public static void main(String []args){
  System.out.println("hello world" + new HelloWorld().name);
}
```

Or,

```
static String name = "asad";
public static void main(String []args){
  System.out.println("hello world" + name);
}
```

Or,

```
public static void main(String []args){
  String name = "asad";
  System.out.println("hello world" + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: make `name` static; i.e:

```
static String name = "asad";
```

Long answer: You need to understand the difference between static and non-static. `static` properties and methods are attached to the *class*. This means that they are available *without* an instance of the class, and more importantly, shared between *all* instances (because they belong to the class itself).

On the other hand, non-static properties and methods *belong to the instance of the class only*. These are things that belong to a particular *instance* of the class.

The problem you are facing is that `main` is `static`. Since `main` is invoked on the class itself, it has no idea what `name` is, because `name` is attached to an *instance*. Hence `name` is undefined in the static context.

Another way, other than making `name` static, is to forcibly create an instance of the class and then reference `name` that way:

```
new HelloWorld().name;
```

But this isn't really good style. You need to think long and hard about what properties/methods need to be static, and which don't. Static properties introduce another wrinkle in the sense that you now have shared state, which can lead to interesting or undesirable behavior if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that main is static,  meaning it exists without you having to initialize the class it's in.  However, the string you are trying to print is not static,  meaning it only exists if the class is initialized.  The compiler sees that it's possible for main to be called without the object being created  (because it's static), and that means it won't be able to access the string to print,  because it doesn't  exist,  so it complains.  You need to make the string you are trying to print static as well.

```
static String name = "asad";
```