# Static Reference Error

Tags: static, processing

As of right now I am trying to print some text on a screen when a variable is a certain value.

My code is reporting a "Cannot make a static reference…" error for the line `if(ElementButton.showElement[0] == 2)`:

```
void buildDiatomicMolecules(){

   if(ElementButton.showElement[0] == 2){

   textSize(18);

   text("H", g.eXLocation/2, g.eYLocation/2 - g.eYLocation/8); 
   }
```

In this case ElementButton is a class. Do I need to make the ElementButton class static?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Make Static Reference to Non-Static Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method) (or more precisely, since its a field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200740/java-making-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field-list?rq=1)

Comment: `showElement` should be a static member of `ElementButton`.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of static methods and classes in Java?

Comment: @Joshua Siktar can you also please list how you initialize ElementButton ?

Comment: ElementButton(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH, Element tempElement) 
  {
    super(tempX, tempY, tempW, tempH);
    //below line retraces steps to find the element symbol currently being stored in element
    buttonText = tempElement.getSymbol();
    element = tempElement;
  }